# why do Realm generate proxy classes for all the model class?

Tags: android, database, nosql, realm, proxy-classes

I am trying to understand how does Realm for Android works under the hood. when I used the custom methods in our model class, couldn't see them in the generated proxy class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proxy classes extend your model class, which is why they cannot be `final` and need to be marked `open` in Kotlin, but that means that the proxy class automatically inherit all the methods from your model class.

You can read https://academy.realm.io/posts/is-realm-magic-makoto-yamazaki/ if you are interested in more detail.